# CakePHP containables and model associations

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm new to CakePHP and made a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164716/model-associations-for-cakephp) about issues I was having with relations and finding data. It turned out that my relations appeared to be ok, but the search could be done using containables.

Say I have 3 tables: reservations, reservation_details and rooms with the following data

```
table reservations
id  |  confirmation_number   |   guest_id
1         123                        1

table reservation_details -a reservation can have multiple entries (multiple rooms)
id  |  reservation_id   |   date     |  time   | room_id    |   rate
 2           1            2014-18-04    13:00        1           9.99
 3           1            2014-18-04    13:00        2           4.99

table rooms - an entry in reservation_details has one room_id
id  |       Name       |     Location
 1          Room  1          building A      
 2          Room 2           building A
```

Here are my models/associations

```
 //Reservation model
 public $actsAs = array('Containable');
 public $hasMany = array('ReservationDetail', 'Payment');

 //ReservationDetail model
 public $actsAs = array('Containable');
 public $belongsTo = array('Reservation');
 public $hasMany = array('Room' => array('foreignKey' = 'id'));

 //Room model
 public $actsAs = array('Containable');
 public $belongsTo = array('ReservationDetail' => array('foreignKey' => 'room_id'));
```

What I'm trying to do is search for a reservation and also return the reservation_details and room information. Right now all of the data is being returned, except the for the room information which is an empty array.  Here's the search I'm trying to do

```
$reservation = $this->Reservation->find('all', array(
                                          'conditions' => array(
                                             'Reservation.guest_id' => $guest_id
                                           ),
                                           'contain' => array(
                                               'ReservationDetail' => array(
                                                        'Room'
                                                 )
                                             )
                                       ));
```

I believe the MySQL query would be something like

```
SELECT reservations.*, reservation_details.*, rooms.* from reservations
INNER JOIN reservation_details on reservation_details.reservation_id = reservation.id
INNER JOIN rooms on rooms.id = reservation_details.room_id
WHERE reservations.guest_id = '1'
```

Comment: There is a typo in 'foreignKey' = 'id', should be 'foreignKey' => 'id'. Maybe You've got the same typo in your code?

Comment: add a new field on rooms table as `reservation_id` as `foreign key` for `reservations` table.. And don't need to add `Containable` behavior to all of you Model... Just add this on AppModel...

Comment: Try to use bake for models associations, it's make you life a lot easier

Comment: @FazalRasel the rooms table just contains information about the room itself...Each room can be used for multiple reservations. That's why I have a room_id in the reservation_details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong relations between models.
Replace them with:

```
//Reservation model
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $hasMany = array('ReservationDetail', 'Payment');

//ReservationDetail model
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $belongsTo = array('Reservation', 'Room');

//Room model
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $hasMany = array('ReservationDetail');
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. The only thing I had to do was add a foreign key in the Room model ('ReservationDetail' => array('foreignKey' => 'room_id'))